# Oracle SQL, assigning names if value holds true for different cases

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case

I have this problem which I am not able to solve.

```
with t as (
select 'Apple' a, 2016 yr from dual
union all select 'Tesla' a, 2016 yr from dual
union all select 'Microsoft' a, 2016 yr from dual
union all select 'Google' a, 2016 yr from dual
union all select 'Apple' a, 2017 yr from dual
union all select 'Google' a, 2017 yr from dual
union all select 'Apple' a, 2018 yr from dual
union all select 'Amazon' a, 2018 yr from dual
union all select 'Tesla' a, 2018 yr from dual
union all select 'Nvdia' a, 2018 yr from dual
)

select * from t;
```

I want to assign a value 'Good' if the data exists in column 'a' for all 3 Years
assign a value 'Average' if the data exists in the column 'a' for 2 Years any combination (2016, 2017) or (2017, 2018) or (2016,2018)
assign a value 'Bad' if the data exists in the column 'a' for only 1 Year (2016) or (2017) or (2018)

Desired Output:

[image]

I have tried the (Case) method, it appears to not work.

SQL FIDDLE UK HERE
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7eda42b2658ee571f7a2e66fd57c0c09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` in its analytic form might help.

```
SQL> with t as (
  2  select 'Apple' a, 2016 yr from dual
  3  union all select 'Tesla' a, 2016 yr from dual
  4  union all select 'Microsoft' a, 2016 yr from dual
  5  union all select 'Google' a, 2016 yr from dual
  6  union all select 'Apple' a, 2017 yr from dual
  7  union all select 'Google' a, 2017 yr from dual
  8  union all select 'Apple' a, 2018 yr from dual
  9  union all select 'Amazon' a, 2018 yr from dual
 10  union all select 'Tesla' a, 2018 yr from dual
 11  union all select 'Nvdia' a, 2018 yr from dual
 12  )
 13  select a, yr,
 14    case when count(*) over (partition by a) = 3 then 'good'
 15         when count(*) over (partition by a) = 2 then 'average'
 16         when count(*) over (partition by a) = 1 then 'bad'
 17    end res
 18  From t
 19  order by yr, a;

A                 YR RES
--------- ---------- -------
Apple           2016 good
Google          2016 average
Microsoft       2016 bad
Tesla           2016 average
Apple           2017 good
Google          2017 average
Amazon          2018 bad
Apple           2018 good
Nvdia           2018 bad
Tesla           2018 average

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Littlefoot I thought I had to use decode. didn't know about the count(*) technique.